# Potentially complicated query for hasMany relationship; can this be done?

Tags: mysql, sql

A `Person` can have many `Degree` records.

Person

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstName | varchar(60)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Degree *(edit: I've hidden many additional fields for simplicity)*

```
+----------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)                       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| personID | int(11)                       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type     | enum('PhD','MSE','MEng','MA') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

On a web page, I want to display a list of people and their degree information *(there's other info to a degree other than their type, I've just not included it for simplicity)*. I believe this will have to be done in N+1 queries. First, a query to select all people that have degrees:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person.id
FROM person
JOIN degree ON degree.personID = person.id
```

And then when iterating through each result, query for their degrees directly:

```
SELECT * FROM degree WHERE personID = :personID
```

However, my life is not that simple. I have two additional requirements:

1. Allow filtering the page based on degree. ex: "Only show people with 'MA' degrees", "Only show people with 'MSE' degrees".
2. Only show 'MA' degrees if the person does not also have a 'PhD' degree.

I'm struggling with how to incorporate these requirements into the queries. For the first requirement, the main query needs to know beforehand what degrees the user has. Do I need a sub-query here?

The rule also somehow needs to be involved in the main query (as well as second query that loads the degrees).

Comment: Just a minor comment, it's columns, not fields...

Comment: I just copied output from mysql's `describe` command

Comment: Ha ha, sorry... Didn't know they have their own terms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple queries for this.  I assume you want the degrees in a list, such as this:

```
SELECT p.id, group_concat(d.type)
FROM person p JOIN
     degree d
     ON d.personID = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

For filtering, you would use `having`.  For instance, the following would always return PhDs:

```
HAVING sum(d.degree = 'phd') > 0
```

The "MA"/"PhD" issue adds some complication:

```
SELECT p.id,
       (case when sum(d.degree = 'phd') > 0
             then group_concat(case when d.type <> 'ma' then d.type end)
             else group_concat(d.type)
        end) as degrees
FROM person p JOIN
     degree d
     ON d.personID = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: The `degree` table is more complicated than what I've shown, so there's more to it than just the type (there's also conferred year, thesis, etc), so I don't think the first query you provided will apply, since I need to provide a lot more info for each degree

Comment: I would use HAVING INSTR(group_concat(d.type), 'MA')>0 AND INSTR(group_concat(d.type), 'phd')=0 (or the same with LOCATE)

Comment: @StanislavL . . . There is no reason to do a `group_concat()`, which is a more expensive operation than a simple `sum()`.

Comment: @Brian . . . I (or anyone else) can only answer the question that you ask.  If you have a substantially different question, you should ask another question.  It is impolite to change a question, after it has answers, in such a way that the answers are invalidated -- that can draw downvotes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your answer more or less answered my original question, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on Gordon Linoff's answer.

You can use the Gordon's approach to filter out the persons first (in a subquery) and then join their degrees in one query.

```
SELECT degree.* 
FROM degree JOIN
    (SELECT p.id as personID, group_concat(d.type) as deg_info
    FROM person p JOIN
         degree d
         ON d.personID = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id
    HAVING INSTR(deg_info, 'MA')>0 
           AND INSTR(deg_info, 'phd')=0) filter ON degree.personId=filter.personID
```